# Javascript error for ie9 - flickrshow gallery

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have a page with two flickrshow galleries on it.  They both work fine in FF, Chrome, Safari, ie6+ but not ie9.  I am fixing various js problems by using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

to emulate ie8.  Problem is that there is still an error for the js and ie is throwing up the 'webpage error, do you want to debug' message each load.

Using the Debugger, error is:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'removeChild': object is null or undefined 
flickrshow-7.2.min.js, line 11 character 4468
```

The line of the flickrshow js that gets highlighted with the error on:

```
a.elements.script.parentNode.removeChild(a.elements.script)
```

Suggestions please, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't given much context for your code. Try logging `a.elements.script.parentNode` and `a.elements.script` and `a` to see if you actually are getting the elements your expecting. From the error I assume since it has something to do with IE not getting the HTML element correctly.  However, it could be something with `a` I'm assuming it is a variable for something, but I'm not sure what.